# Access method 'Facebook.HttpHelper.UrlDecode(System.String)' failed - WinPhone8

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8

I've installed the latest Facebook.Client package to try and integrate facebook on my Windows Phone 8 game. The connection to log in is fine but upon trying to return to the game app, I get the following error message:

"Attempt by method 'Facebook.Client.AppAuthenticationHelper.GetQueryStringValueFromUri(System.String, System.String)' to access method 'Facebook.HttpHelper.UrlDecode(System.String)' failed."

The Facebook package is present in my solution (installed as a dependency of Facebook.Client, if memory serves), but this does not appear to have an HttpHelper class.

Can anyone advise on what I need to get this working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. You probably installed Facebook.Client from nuget, it installs Facebook.Client and its dependency - FacebookSDK. It seems that FacebookSDK package installed by default is in old version - not fully working with Facebook.Client. Solution is really simple - execute nuget command for installation of new version of Facebook SDK.
like this one:

```
Install-Package Facebook -Version 7.0.6
```